# GORM Paginate - on next page get one row from previous call

Tags: go, go-gorm

I use GORM and I paginate my data. I get `n` rows each time. Unfortunately I need to compare row with previous one. Is there a way in GORM to fetch exclusive `n` rows and one from previous call? When I set offset to `n+1` it does not get that one previous row.

Example:

```
// page=1 limit=3

[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "A": 12,
    "B": 434,
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "A": 456,
    "B": 786,
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "A": 23,
    "B": 978,
  }
]

// ... compare if A is equal in previous object and
return [{
    "id": 1,
    "A": 12,
    "B": 434,
    "isGreater": false,
  },{
    "id": 2,
    "A": 456,
    "B": 786,
    "isGreater": true,
  },{
    "id": 3,
    "A": 23,
    "B": 978,
    "isGreater": false,
  }]
```

and

```
// page=2 limit=3
// from db fetch 4 rows
[
  {
    "id": 3,
    "A": 12,
    "B": 434,
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "A": 456,
    "B": 786,
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "A": 23,
    "B": 978,
  },
  {
    "id": 6,
    "A": 23445,
    "B": 978,
  }
]

// but return only 3
return [{
    "id": 4,
    "A": 12,
    "B": 434,
    "isGreater": false,
  },{
    "id": 5,
    "A": 456,
    "B": 786,
    "isGreater": true,
  },{
    "id": 6,
    "A": 23,
    "B": 978,
    "isGreater": true,
  }]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Custom Preloading SQL](https://gorm.io/docs/preload.html#Custom-Preloading-SQL), to set offset with a limit number record to retrieve.

Sample codes

```
db.Preload("Orders", func(db *gorm.DB) *gorm.DB { 
    return db.Offset(0).Limit(10)
})
```

---

**Update**

Another option for paginate is to use the [`FindByPage`](https://github.com/go-gorm/gen/blob/master/examples/dal/query/mytables.gen.go#L257) of [GORM Gen](https://gorm.io/gen/index.html)

```golang
func (m mytableDo) FindByPage(offset int, limit int) (result []*model.Mytable, count int64, err error) {
    count, err = m.Count()
    if err != nil {
        return
    }

    result, err = m.Offset(offset).Limit(limit).Find()
    return
}
```

Comment: I have message `Data: unsupported relations for schema Data`. And if I understand documentation correctly Preload is not for this purpose.

Comment: @Nju, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66810464/unsupported-relations-in-gorm, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67303897/unsupported-relations-for-schema, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67579704/unsupported-relations-in-gorm-nested-preload. Hope those related question could help you

Comment: I saw it. It is not my case. I have one table `Data` with two columns